# Onboard ethernet drivers for Android-x86?

Tags: hardware, android-x86, lan

I have recently installed Android-x86 6.0 RC1 on a USB Flash drive, so I can test compatibility in various PCs and notebooks. One thing I noticed is that the Ethernet card is never detected (probably no driver) and the only option is to use the Wi-Fi card (for notebooks) or a Wi-Fi USB dongle (for PCs). This is not very convenient, at least for PCs. Is there any way to make the build-in Ethernet card work? I know there is a USB Ethernet adapter that works in Android, but this is pointless. If I have to use a USB adapter, I would use a USB Wi-Fi dongle. The point is to use the build-in Ethernet so I won't need to add anything extra to the PC. Is there any driver for the most common LAN cards such as Realtek RTL8111F and its variants found on many modern motherboards? How do I install it? Any app that can enable Ethernet?

Thank you in advance

UPDATE: No drivers needed, LAN works out of the box. I didn't realize it because I expected to see something relevant to Ethernet in Settings and was nothing there. When connecting the LAN cable it shows a <-> icon top right at the bar. As long as you see that you are online, that's it. Actually I am not sending this update from an old notebook that the WiFi is not detected by Android but the LAN works! Thank you all!

Comment: My built-in ethernet and dongle are both detected and working. I don't know about the chips they use though. Also it'd be nigh impossible to add drivers to Android unless you're building it.